# Where can I find RNA seq data (filename.fastq) for normal human sample?

Tags: fastq, rna-seq

Where to find publicly available normal human sample (non-disease) RNA seq data in fastq format, preferably sequenced using Illumina platform. Where can I find such fastq file?